# quicksort using an arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, quicksort

I've written a quicksort for an arraylist and as it stands the logic seems to be sound. The problem I'm having is in the swapping of elements. What seems to be happening is rather than swapping the elements, the method is replacing the existing element with the one to be swapped. an example run start out with a list like [happy, apples, eat, food] and after the sort runs, it comes out [happy, happy, happy, food]. I'm sure my mistake is simple, but I've been staring at it for too long and need fresh eyes on it. Here's my code so far. Thanks in advance!

```
String pivot = list.get(0); // Choose the first element as the pivot
      int low = first + 1; // Index for forward search
      int high = last; // Index for backward search

      while (high > low) 
      { // Search forward from left
          while (low <= high && list.get(low).compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
          {

              low++;
          }
      // Search backward from right
      while (low <= high && list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) > 0)
      {
          high--;
      }
      // Swap two elements in the list
      if (high > low) 
      {

          String temp = list.get(high);
          list.set(high,list.get(low));
          list.set(low,temp);

      }
    }
    while (high > first && list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
    {

        high--;
    }
    // Swap pivot with list[high]
    if (list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) < 0) 
    { 
        list.set(first, list.get(high));
        list.set(high,pivot);
        return high;
    }
    else 
    {
        return first;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `String pivot = list.get(0); // Choose the first element as the pivot` <- that should be `list.get(first)`.

Comment: Thanks, I did catch that after I posted the code, however it does nothing to fix the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (after fixing the pivot selection to use `list.get(first)`) is

```
while (high > first && list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
```

At that point, all elements before (and including) the index `high` are (lexicographically) smaller than, or equal to the pivot. Thus

while (high > first && list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
    {

```
    high--;
}
```

can be abbreviated to `high = first`.

That explains the duplication of the first element with the

```
String pivot = list.get(0);
```

pivot selection, because in your example the element at index 0 is the largest, hence the

```
if (list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) < 0) 
{ 
    list.set(first, list.get(high));
    list.set(high,pivot);
    return high;
}
```

branch is taken, `list.set(first, list.get(high));` does nothing because `high == first`, and then `list.set(high,pivot);` copies the pivot to the index `high (== first)`.

What you need in the problematic line is

```
if (list.get(high).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
    --high;
}
```

If after the first partitioning loop the element at index `high` is larger than the pivot, the one before is less than or equal to the pivot. Otherwise, `high` is the largest index of an element not larger than the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think the mistake is simple. Try this

```
String tempHigh = list.get(high);
String tempLow = list.get(low);
list.set(high, tempLow);
list.set(low, tempHigh);
```

Because in java assignment is done thru reference. In your code you are simply setting high value to both high & low positions. Same thing goes when you swapping pivot with list[high]

Comment: I tried this approach and unfortunately, it didn't fix my problem. My issue may be bigger than I originally thought.